# How to get rid of the nested double quote in 'name' subfield?

Tags: python, json, regex, double-quotes

I am trying to read the following string into a dictionary using Python json package

However, under one of the subfield 'name' there is a description with a nested double quote. My json is unable to read the string that way

```
import json 

string1 = 
'{"id":17033,"project_id":17033,"state":"active","state_changed_at":1488054590,"name":"a.k.a.:\xa0"The Sunshine Makers""'

json.loads(string1)
```

A ERROR was raised

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 96 (char 95)
```

I know that the reason for this error was due to the nested double quote around "The Sunshine Makers"

**How to I get rid of this double quote?**

More examples of string that cause error

```
string2 = '{"id":960066,"project_id":960066,"state":"active","state_changed_at":1502049940,"name":"New J. Lye Album - Behind The Lyes","blurb":"I am working on my new project titled "Behind The Lyes" which is coming out fall of 2017."'

#The problem with this string comes from the nested double quote around the pharse "Behind The Lyes inside" the 'blurb' subfield
```

Comment: Your strings are also missing a closing `}`. Be sure that problem is addressed.

Comment: If you wish to preserve the quoting, your can get around the problem by nesting `json.dumps()` withing your `json.loads()`: `print(json.loads(json.dumps(string1)))`

Comment: Where is string1 coming from? Is that something you're creating in code, or grabbing from a website or database?

Comment: Also, `line 1, column 96 (char 95)` in your error is `\xa0`.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. Fix the input, instead of trying to figure out how to work around its errors in your script.

Comment: Hi all, the string is from a large dataframe, I will not have time to fix each and every single one. Also the reason for the missing } is because I cut the string short to show only relevant portion. Regarding the \x I forgot to add strict=False into json.loads - But the error message talks about the delimiter ',' rather than a special control character (which I got from other strings with a \n character for example)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding why we're asking about your source data. Wherever that is coming from, there's where you need to fix your parsing. Can you share an [mcve] that includes code that generates your dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your string has more than one issue making it invalid `JSON`:

The error you're seeing is the `\xa0` (a non-breaking space). That needs to be addressed before the `""` issue becomes a problem.

Your string is missing a closing `}`.

That said, for the string you've cited first, one approach to fixing your issues would be to use `.replace()`:

```
string1 = '{"id":17033,"project_id":17033,"state":"active","state_changed_at":1488054590,"name":"a.k.a.:\xa0"The Sunshine Makers""'.replace('\xa0"', "'").replace('""', "'\"") + '}'
```

For example, the following handles the double quoting and other issues in your two sample strings:

```
import json 

fixes = [('\xa0', ' '),('"',"'"),("{'",'{"'),("','", '","'),(",'", ',"'),("':'", '":"'),("':", '":'),("''", '\'\"'), ("'}",'"}')]

print(fixes)
string1 = '{"id":17033,"project_id":17033,"state":"active","state_changed_at":1488054590,"name":"a.k.a.:\xa0"The Sunshine Makers""'
string2 = '{"id":960066,"project_id":960066,"state":"active","state_changed_at":1502049940,"name":"New J. Lye Album - Behind The Lyes","blurb":"I am working on my new project titled "Behind The Lyes" which is coming out fall of 2017."'
strings = [string1, string2]

for string in strings:
    print(string)
    string = string + '}'
    for fix in fixes:
        string = string.replace(*fix)
    print(string)
    print(json.loads(string)['name'])
```

It would be helpful if you could fill out your question with the code or file from which you are retrieving these strings. That would make it possible to give a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried replace before but it is too complicated because I had to address every single unique patterns (I have 100000+ rows of unique entries, above are just 2 examples). Is there a more simple way to do this?

Comment: The more simple way is going to be fixing the parser that creates your dataframe. Your data is going to be just too random if it's as you describe.